# typescript: needing an asserted type during return?

Tags: typescript

I am new to TypeScript and I'm having an issue with type assertion.  I have a function that is expecting the type `DataLog` to come back.  My editor was showing an issue with the type when I just did `return allPhotoData`, even though the shape of the return data was exactly like a `DataLog` type.  However, the editor message goes away when I do `return allPhotoData as DataLog`.  Is this acceptable way of handling it?

```
async function setDataTypes(
  userId: string | number,
): Promise<DataLog | undefined | null> {

 const indexPhoto = await api.getIndexPhotoData(
    userId,
   'subType'),
 );

  const { allPhotoData } = keyBy(indexPhoto, () => {
    return 'allPhotoData';
  });

  return allPhotoData as DataLog;
}
```

Comment: Your function is not expecting a `DataLog`; it's expecting a `Promise`, which is not what you're giving it

Comment: @SilvioMayolo sorry, I just added the missing part of the function that contains the promise

Comment: I am sure lots of more experience folks have recommendations but I prefer not specifying the return so I can see what the compile thinks. To answer your question, adding `as DataLog` basically says, "whatever is in here, I'm guaranteeing that it is a DataLog". Doing "as" doesn't actually validate that the `allPhotoData` has the properties of a DataLog. To do that you can check individual with `typeof` or use a library like io-ts.

Comment: Seems like you aren't actually returning a promise that resolves to `Datalog | undefined | null` and is warning you about it. Figure out where you're going wrong instead of overruling it with `as Datalog`. In this case it looks like you might be returning a `string`.

Comment: Please include the exact error message you are getting